# Android: Store path of an MediaStore image for later use

Tags: java, android, image, mediastore

I succesfully pick an image from gallery or camera and then save it to MediaStore using this code whithin my OnActivityResult:

```
public static void saveBitmap(@NonNull final Context context, @NonNull final Bitmap bitmap,
                            @NonNull final Bitmap.CompressFormat format, @NonNull final String mimeType,
                            @NonNull final String displayName) throws IOException
    {
        final String relativeLocation = Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES + File.separator +"MYAPPNAME";

        final ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, displayName);
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, mimeType);
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, relativeLocation);

        final ContentResolver resolver = context.getContentResolver();

        OutputStream stream = null;
        Uri uri = null;

        try
        {
            final Uri contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            uri = resolver.insert(contentUri, contentValues);

            if (uri == null)
            {
                throw new IOException("Failed to create new MediaStore record.");
            }

            stream = resolver.openOutputStream(uri);

            if (stream == null)
            {
                throw new IOException("Failed to get output stream.");
            }

            if (bitmap.compress(format, 95, stream) == false)
            {
                throw new IOException("Failed to save bitmap.");
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            if (uri != null)
            {
                // Don't leave an orphan entry in the MediaStore
                resolver.delete(uri, null, null);
            }

            throw e;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (stream != null)
            {
                stream.close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Now lets say, later while using the app, i want to load this specific image for display in an imageview or upload it or whatsoever. How can i adress this specific image programatically? I dont quite understand the path/file system of the mediastore for later access. Any ideas?

Comment: `I succesfully pick an image from gallery or camera and then save it to MediaStore ` That makes no sense if you pick an image from Gallery as then the MediaStore already knows that image. Please explain why you would store another time. Start your post with it please.

Comment: `How can i adress this specific image programatically? ` Save `uri.toString() somewhere.` Then later retrieve the string and parse to an uri. You then have your content scheme back.

Comment: `I succesfully pick an image from gallery or camera and then`.. That is irrelevant as all what we can see from your code is that you have a bitmap. And you are saving a bitmap to the media store. Irrelevant where and how you obtained your bitmap.